# Using libsodium in an android studio project

Tags: android, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I am trying to utilize the libsodium library in an android studio project. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. I have the library downloaded from the libsodium website, but do not understand how to create the library files necessary for an android studio project. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I imagine that kalium (https://github.com/abstractj/kalium) would help me do this, but am slightly confused on how to incorporate that as well.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's quite late, but if you want a starting point, this answer could help you: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28627827/3424545).

Also, now there are many helpers to use libsodium in Android, like this github project: [Robosodium](https://github.com/GerardSoleCa/Robosodium).

Answer (score 0):

libsodium themselves [recommends](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages) [lazysodium-android](https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-android)